# Restrict child process 's cpu and ram usage by parent process using C/C++ in Linux

Tags: linux, cpu, c, ram, c++

I am trying to create child processes from parent processes.I want to restrict  CPU and RAM usage of the child processes using C/C++.Is there is a way to  do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On older Unices, this was done with the ulimit(2) system call, current Linux uses getrlimit(2), sysconf(3)/setrlimit(2). Check out the manual pages. You'd create the child process by fork(2), set it's limits, and then use one of the exec(3) calls to start the desired program.